# How to post List or ICollection of model type as Model Property?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a code where I have two models and one view. Parent model contains Child model's List collection.

My problem is I when I submit my form at that time I am binding a Json to the  hidden input which reference to the parent model's property which is nothing but a List collection of child model.

At receiving model at ActionResult I found that collection is null. While Input tag holds the Json in string format but it is not available at ActionResult.

Here is Errata Model (Parent):

```
[Key]
public string ID { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage =" Errata Title is mandatory !")]
public string Title { get; set; }    
public List<Affected_Mask> affected_Mask { get; set; }
```

Here is Affected_Mask Model (Child):

```
[Key]
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Errata_ID { get; set; }
public int Mask_ID { get; set; }
```

Html Hidden Input:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.affected_Mask)
```

JSON:

```
maskDetails = { "ID": ID, "Errata_ID": Errata_ID, "Mask_ID": maskID }
```

JavaScript to bind json to html element:

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#affected_Mask").value = JSON.stringify(affected_mask_json);
        $(this).unbind("submit").submit();
    });
```

Comment: You cannot bind an input to a collection of complex objects (you would need  an input for each property of each item in the collection). But since you not even editing anything relating to the collection, then it would be pointless to send it all to the client and send it all back again unchanged. (and `JSON.stringify()` creates a string which could never bind to your `affected_Mask ` property.)

Comment: Is it good approach to create dynamically same named elements for number of items in collection ? such like generating elements before submitting form.

Comment: If you want to create form controls for a collection property, then refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943). But again, it makes no sense (and is degrading performance and opening your self to hackers) to send it to the client and then send it back again when you already know it on the server.